# Why exporting ListItem component complains? Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Below is the example, but I am trying to export ListItem component from Material-UI.

```
import ListItem, { ListItemProps } from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';

export const MyListItem = (props: ListItemProps) => (
    <ListItem {...props} />
);
```

But the error message is :
[image]

what is complaining this about? I've passed button={true} but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know what's wrong with your code. From my point of view, it should work. So you'd better create an issue for the @material-ui. But just in case you need a temporary solution, I found a workaround which solves any TS problem ever:

```
import ListItem, { ListItemProps } from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';

interface MyListItemProps extends ListItemProps {
  button?: any
}

export const MyListItem = (props: MyListItemProps) => (
    <ListItem {...props} />
);
```